# How to get permalink using get_blog_post function in a multisite?

Tags: multisite, permalinks

I'm using code like this

```
$post = get_blog_post( $blog_id, $data );
   echo __('Post on') . ' "<a href="'.$post->guid.'">' . $post->post_title . '</a>"';
```

But the href link looks like this `mysubdomain.example.com/?p=345`  instead of permalink.

Can anyone tell me how to get permalink ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the answer.

```
$post = get_blog_post( $blog_id, $data );
$link = get_blog_permalink( $blog_id, $data );
echo __('Post on') . ' "<a href="'.$link.'">' . $post->post_title . '</a>"';
```

I hope it will be useful for others :)